# International Targeting SEO - hreflang

Tags: seo, google-search-console, local-seo

How do I properly put `hreflang` tags?

I would like to target 3 different languages not just English.

- `example.com/de`
- `example.com/fr`
- `example.com/it`

And my main website `example.com` is in English and it should target everything else worldwide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.internationalseomap.com/hreflang-tags-generator/ is useful.

For example, it told me to put this HTML in the `<head>` section for French in France.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr" hreflang="fr-fr" />
```

If you don't specify countries you can put this in your specific `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr" hreflang="fr" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/it" hreflang="it" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="en" />
```

This will be independent from countries according to [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).

Comment: `<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="en" />`
Will this code limit "example.com" to only english speaking countries like UK,AU,USA?

Comment: No. Google's documentation about `hreflang="en"`: "For example, you may have specific URLs for English speakers in Ireland (en-ie), Canada (en-ca), and Australia (en-au), but want all other English speakers to see your generic English (en) page"